# Laravel AND, Multiple OR eloquent query not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

The Query:

```
Need::Where('student_id', '!=', $id)->Where($matchto)->orWhere($matchfrom)->orWhere($matchstandard)->orWhere($matchlives_in)->orWhere($matchhobbies)->orWhere($matchskills)->orWhere($matchspecialization_1)->orWhere($matchdesignation_1)->get();
```

It Produce the Result query like this

```
"query" => "select * from `needs` where `student_id` != ? and (`to` = ?) or (`from` = ?) or (`standard` = ?) or (`lives_in` = ?) or (`hobbies` = ?) or (`skills` = ?) or (`specialization_1` = ?) or (`designation_1` = ?)"
```

What i want is

```
"query" => "select * from `needs` where `student_id` != ? and **(**(`to` = ?) or (`from` = ?) or (`standard` = ?) or (`lives_in` = ?) or (`hobbies` = ?) or (`skills` = ?) or (`specialization_1` = ?) or (`designation_1` = ?)**)**"
```

An extra bracket after student_id` != ? and. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest your condition:

```
Need::Where('student_id', '!=', $id)
     ->where(function ($query) use ($matchto, $matchfrom, $matchstandard, $matchlives_in, $matchhobbies, $matchskills, $matchspecialization_1, $matchdesignation_1) {
        return $query->where($matchto)->orWhere($matchfrom)->orWhere($matchstandard)->orWhere($matchlives_in)->orWhere($matchhobbies)->orWhere($matchskills)->orWhere($matchspecialization_1)->orWhere($matchdesignation_1);
    })->get();
```

Comment: it show undefined variable $matchto and all other variables inside nest, how to pass those variable inside that nest condition

Comment: got it with use ($variable) Need::Where('student_id', '!=', $id)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($matchto, $matchfrom, $matchstandard, $matchlives_in, $matchhobbies, $matchskills, $matchspecialization_1, $matchdesignation_1) {
     return $query->where($matchto)->orWhere($matchfrom)->orWhere($matchstandard)->orWhere($matchlives_in)->orWhere($matchhobbies)->orWhere($matchskills)->orWhere($matchspecialization_1)->orWhere($matchdesignation_1);
    })->paginate(5);

Comment: @VArunKumar yes, missed that part. Updated